# Import Error with Flask Application Running in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm trying to run a Flask application inside a Docker container, but I'm encountering an import error. The error message is "Could not import 'backend'". Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

# ... (other Docker commands)

# Set environment variables
ENV FLASK_APP=backend
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/${username}/src

# Copy the application code and environment file
COPY ./src /home/${username}
COPY ./.env /home/${username}/.env

# Expose port 5000/TCP default for Flask-API
EXPOSE 5000

# Run the Flask application
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

And here's my `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="backend",
    version="0.1",
    author="Super Company",
    description="Super Project",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages(where="src", include=["backend*"], exclude=["test"]),
    python_requires=">=3.10",
)
```

And this my Project Structure:

```
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── backend
    │   ├── Util.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── api
    │   │   ├── Authentication
    │   │   │   ├── Route_login.py
    │   │   │   ├── Route_resetpass.py
    │   │   │   ├── Route_signup.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── Route_info.py
    │   │   ├── Timesheet
    │   │   │   ├── Route
    │   │   │   │   ├── Route_Search.py
    │   │   │   │   ├── Route_Timesheet.py
    │   │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   │   ├── Search_Helper.py
    │   │   │   ├── Timesheet_Helper.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── User
    │   │   │   ├── Route_User.py
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── database.py
    │   ├── dummy_data.py
    │   ├── logs.py
    │   ├── models
    │   │   ├── TimeSheet.py
    │   │   ├── User.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── schedule_timesheet_job.py
    ├── requirements.txt
```

The error is:

```
| Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
api-backend-1  | Try 'flask run --help' for help.
api-backend-1  |
api-backend-1  | Error: Could not import 'backend
```

I've tried several solutions, including checking my application structure, Dockerfile's COPY commands, Flask application's import statements, PYTHONPATH, application's dependencies, and application logs, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, I have not faced a similar issue w/ `setuptools` before and `DockerFile` before but you could make sure that you are setting the correct `WORKDIR`.

Comment: @MuneebAhmadKhurram, I already tried, I updated my Dockerfile, still getting same error.